# Angular: ERROR TypeError: this.interceptor.intercept is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, http, module.exports, http-interceptor

Estaba tratando de utilizar un HttpInterceptors de Angular, para "interceptar" una petición http, pero me encontré con una serie de problemas en el camino. Seguía un tutorial de DominiCode(excelente Youtuber, les dejo el link por si quieren ver sobre él: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQprcZ0FYMw) para interceptar una petición http y mostrar un Spinner mientras espera que cargue la información de la petición, pero llegué a un punto en donde mi app se quebró y leyendo un poco me di cuenta que:

No estaba llamando mi intercepto.ts en el app.module que es donde llamamos el HttpClientModule, y leyendo en internet entendi que era porque todos los interceptores están configurados para funcionar en una sola instancia del servicio HttpClient. Cosa que no estaba haciendo, asi que verificando mi error, lo había dejado algo como esto:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: SpinnerService,
    multi: true,
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Pero al dejarlo así seguía recibiendo el error: **class interceptor is not a module**. Así que seguí investigando y leyendo del porque pasa esto en Angular, entonces terminé en el blog de @aboukone (https://medium.com/code-divoire/angular-when-httpinterceptor-doesnt-work-with-lazy-loaded-modules-26ae5b694b75) En donde según sus palabras, esto ocurre porque es como si se estuviera creando una nueva instancia del servicio HttpClient cada que vez que se necesita por lo que no esta pasando por el intercepto tal como afirma @RandoShtishi (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64991922/interceptor-declared-in-app-module-is-not-intercepting-call-from-one-lazy-loaded)

Así que @aboukone propone una solución, la cual es, que configurando un módulo Core con nuestro servicio, podría ser una solución ya que esto "agregaría la definición del proveedor del interceptor en el ámbito del módulo a cada función de carga diferida".Entonces lo configure de la siguiente forma:

**Deje el servicio que muestra/oculta un Spinner, y añadi un Core.module para inyectar mi interceptor**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Y en la class interceptor hize algo como esto:**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { finalize } from "rxjs/operators";
import { SpinnerService } from '../core/spinner.service';

@Injectable()
export class SpinnerInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor{
    constructor(private spinnerSvc: SpinnerService){}
    
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        this.spinnerSvc.show();
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            finalize( () => this.spinnerSvc.hide()));
    }
}
```

Como ven intente investigar lo más posible y leer la documentación, asi como seguir un tutorial pero no llego a una solución ya que aun recibo un error del tipo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sinceramente, no se que más hacer, ya le di vuelta a Google, conceptualize cada cosa que estaba utilizando para entender, diagrame y no llego a la solución. ¿Alguien sabe porque sucede esto? O...es que quizás no tiene nada que ver con mi clase y tal vez es algun tipado que me esta dando rollo, si alguien me comparte de su conocimiento porfis se lo agradeceria porfis, se que me han ayudado bastante en esta comunidad, pero aqui si ando perdida.

Gracias, saludos!

**Nota: Utilizo Angular CLI en su última versión**

****ACTUALIZACION****

Luego de la solución que me han dado, no me muestra el spinner, pero lo que si noto en clg "this.spinner" me esta trayendo lo siguiente, por lo que descarto la posibilidad que venga undefined:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Como muy bien te respondieron tienes que proporcionar la clase del
> interceptor, no del servicio.
> El spinner puede no llegar a verse visualmente dado que la respuesta lo exceda para ver su accion te copio codigo

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SpinnerService {
  
  visibility$=new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
 spinnerVisibility$=this.visibility$.asObservable()
  constructor() {
   
  }

  show():void {
    this.visibility$.next(true);
  }

  hide():void {
    this.visibility$.next(false);
  }
  
  
}
```

> spinner.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 
import { SpinnerRoutingModule } from './spinner-routing.module';
import { SpinnerComponent } from './spinner.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SpinnerInterceptor } from './spinner.interceptor';
import { MaterialModule } from '../material/material.module';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SpinnerComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MaterialModule,
    FormsModule,
    SpinnerRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
     provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
     useClass: SpinnerInterceptor,
     multi:true
    },
   
     ],
})

export class SpinnerModule { }
```

> En el spinner.component.ts la forma de ver por consola el cambio de
> spinner el resto del codigo  en link de github
> [spinner codigo completo](https://github.com/nestdanchia/spinner/tree/main/src/app)

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
   
   this.spinnerService.spinnerVisibility$.subscribe(
     bol=>{this.vi=bol;console.log('spinner:',this.vi)}
   )
  }
  getEmployees() {
    this.httpClient.get<any>
    ('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')
      .subscribe(success => {
        console.log('Done');
      }, error => {
        console.error('Error');
      });
    }
```

> El spinner.component.html

```html
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)=" getEmployees()">Get ......</button> 

<mat-progress-bar color="accent" mode="indeterminate" *ngIf="spinnerService.spinnerVisibility$ | async"></mat-progress-bar>

  
  <mat-spinner [diameter]="50" *ngIf="spinnerService.spinnerVisibility$  | async"></mat-spinner>
```

> El spinner.interceptor.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { SpinnerService } from './spinner.service';

@Injectable()
export class SpinnerInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private spinnerService: SpinnerService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        this.spinnerService.show();

        return next.handle(req)
            .pipe(tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    this.spinnerService.hide();
                }
            }, (error) => {
                this.spinnerService.hide();
            }));
    }
}
```

> Lo que emencionabas sobre que los interceptores deben proporcionarse
> en el mismo inyector (o un padre del inyector) que proporciona
> HttpClient  Esta muy bien explicado en :

[Provide the interceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#http-interceptors)

> El codigo de github mostrara para la ruta spinner para la peticion de user el dodigo de la peticion es extenso lo subi a github

[[peticion user](https://github.com/nestdanchia/spinner/tree/main/src/app)][1](https://github.com/nestdanchia/spinner/tree/main/src/app)

```js
spinner: false spinner.component.ts:62:31
spinner: true spinner.component.ts:62:31
spinner: false spinner.component.ts:62:31
users
```

[spinner codigo](https://github.com/nestdanchia/spinner/tree/main/src/app) 
Para la peticion de Empleados si es visible

> Codigo base el cual modifique para mostrar lo que te comente agregue codigo que permite ver el estado del spinner y un modulo con ruta lazy loading spinner tambien peticiones a otro servidor para comparar la respuesta en :

[loading spinner](https://onthecode.co.uk/angular-display-spinner-every-request/)

Me parece que los interceptores son muy utilies por ejemplo para autentificar un token pero en este tipo de aplicacion spinner ante una peticion no le veo gran utilidad

Comment: ¿Tú crees que no? Es que en si sería para la carga "lenta" de los datos, yo en si lo que estaba haciendo mal era que estaba llamando al servicio y no la clase del interceptor. Luego cuando modifique ello y llame la clase desde donde esta el module http. no me lanzo ningún error pero tampoco me mostraba nada, pero cuando lo cambie a un BehaviorSubject (quien sostiene un valor) en lugar de un Subject. todo anduvo bien ¿porqué sucede esto? Anduve leyendo la diferencia entre ambos, pero realmente curioso que esto suceda

Comment: Y si veo que muchas paginas lo usan a mi como usuario no me agrada pero cada uno tiene sus gustos.Sobre porque no te muestra nada  tene en cuenta que Behaviour Subject recuerda al ultimo valor emitido sin importar el tiempo y lo hace visible a un nuevo subscriptor permite definir un valor por defecto
el cual puede mostrar sin un next() .Me parece que con los console.log() que puse lo podes apreciar

Comment: modifique en github  visibility$=new Subject<boolean>(); y se muestra el spinner  y consola con  mensajes pero mi codigo en el interceptor es distinto Mira este post `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60652498/angular-interceptor-finalize-before-http-request-data-respond`

Comment: ademas tambien capturo en forma distinta  en la vista saludos

Comment: Finalmente probe el proyecto con tu interceptor que usa finalize() y use  subject de la forma que esta en mi github  y tambien funciona

Answer (score 1):

Como proveedor de `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` tienes que proporcionar la clase del interceptor, no del servicio.

```
providers: [{
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: SpinnerInterceptor,  //<--
  multi: true,
}],
```

saludos

Comment: Hola! Gracias por responder, no puedo creer que hubiese sido un error tan sencillo como ese, por eso dicen que es bueno que otros vean tu trabajo porque a ti se te pudo escapar algo, el problema ahora es que no me lanza error pero no me muestra el spinner. He eliminado el modulo core, y simplemente inyecto SpinnerInterceptor.ts en el app.module donde se llama al HttpClient, pero no me muestra nada

Comment: @Izlia eso ya depende de como tengas implementado el servicio y donde y como estés incluyendo el spinner en la aplicación. Sin ver el código no puedo decirte.